# Name manager doesn't allow spaces in EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, dropdownlist

I am creating dependent drop down list in Excel using **Data validation** and  **Name Manager** and the function **Indirect**.

My problem is that the **Name Manager** doesn't allow to have space when defining a new name. Based on Microsoft,this is not allowed and they suggest to put a (_) or (.) instead.

[Define and use names in formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)

[image]

Is there any way to bypass this as I have many names having spaces to put them in the drop down menus.

Comment: You can use =INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","_")) where A1 contain the Name Range

Comment: so you suggest to replace the (_) with a space. Will try it and see.

Comment: Yes give it a try and tell us it will help other users

Comment: Create the define Name with "_" Example key_one but in the list items write it without _ key one and use the formula

Comment: It worked, could you put it as an answer and explain as match as you can?

Comment: I have try it and wrote the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can Define Name for your list with "_" instead of blank but in the List of items in Drop Down list just write space:

```
Registered              first
Will be registered      second
                        third
```

This List Define Name Will_be_registered (first second third)  and in Data Validation use:
List and for Source =INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(A8," ","_")) A8 is where you choose will be registered  In C1 you will have the drop down (first second third)
You cannot use Name Manager with space but you can show your Data with space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my case, if I try to change the A8 to registered,B8 is not refreshing

Comment: Is B8 where you choose will be registered or registered? it should be the first Drop down list options

Comment: Registered has to be Name of a list because of Indirect just select registered where you have it near the list and Name it registered also

Comment: If it is already a Named Range just click on the arrow it will show the corresponding list

Comment: Will this work if the item list (with substitution formula) has its own dependent drop-down menu ?  (I.e. a third level)

Comment: Yes, got it to work as many levels as needed